# Composer asks only for password with private repository

Tags: authentication, repository, composer-php

When I use a private repository like below in my `composer.json`

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "url": "ssh://repo.com/porject",
      "type": "git"
    }
  ],
```

Composer install/update doesn't ask me for my username, it gets the name of the current user of my computer and uses it automatically. It prompts me only for a password.

[image: ask only about password img]

Any idea how to set it correctly and how I can store the auth once typed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to config access via SSH keys or specify your desired username like below. For more information see the [Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#security).

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "ssh2.sftp://example.org",
            "options": {
                "ssh2": {
                    "username": "composer",
                    "pubkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
                    "privkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```